# Send message to standalone Unity application from HTML or command prompt link?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Is there a way to send a message to Unity standalone build from external source? The source could be an html created file or a link through PDF or even from command prompt. I have not started anything since I need an idea of how to approach this.

Comment: There are a bunch of examples out there on controlling unity games with things like python etc, but from html/pdf? id hope the heck not..

Comment: @BugFinder is there a way to send a message from Command Prompt through command line arguments? If so, do you have a link for this?

Comment: well you could probably write something to do that, but no, I do not have a link .. google is your friend SO is not here to recommend books/tutorials etc.

Comment: @DastagirK: can you explain us what you're trying to do? Do you want to send commands to an already running game, or do you want to send commands for the game at startup?

Comment: @AndreasHassing to an already running game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a solution. Here is my C# script:

```
static string cmdInfo = "";

     void Start () 
     {
         string[] arguments = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
         foreach(string arg in arguments)
         {
             cmdInfo += arg.ToString() + "\n ";
         }
     }



     void OnGUI()
     {
         Rect r = new Rect(5,5, 800, 500);
         GUI.Label(r, cmdInfo);
     }
```

and from the project build folder, I am running the following command from command prompt:

```
Halo2 --UserCreated -One
```

"Halo2" is basically the app name and other two are the arguments.

The first time I run the above command, it opens the app. Unfortunately the second time I run the app, it opens another instance of the same app. 
Is there a way to make the command prompt pass the arguments to the same app without opening new one?

Comment: As you noticed, this does not solve your issue. You want to be able to send commands to an already running game. Consider a few options: [TCP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcpclient?view=netframework-4.8)/[UDP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.udpclient?view=netframework-4.8)/[Shared Memory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/memory-mapped-files?redirectedfrom=MSDN)/[NamedPipes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/how-to-use-named-pipes-for-network-interprocess-communication)